# oracle cache mess with mybatis query results (can't get the latest)

Tags: spring, oracle, caching, spring-boot, mybatis

My environment is:
 Spring Boot + Mybatis + Oracle 10g + Jdk1.8

I got a table named book in oracle like this:

```
+---------+------+--------+
| book_id | name | number |
+---------+------+--------+
|       1 | b1   |    123 |
|       2 | b2   |    123 |
|       3 | b3   |   2343 |
+---------+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I got it to work and displayed it successfully with the mapper i wrote .But after i insert 2 more records into this table with plsql,i still got the same 3 records instead of all 5(as below) when i query it with mybatis mapper.

```
+---------+------+--------+  
| book_id | name | number |  
+---------+------+--------+  
|       1 | b1   |    123 |  
|       2 | b2   |    123 |  
|       3 | b3   |   2343 |  
|       4 | b4   |  22343 |  
|       5 | b5   |     43 |  
+---------+------+--------+  
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then i alter the cache strategy in oracle like this.

```
alter table book nocache
```

It worked again!All 5 records are displayed successfully using the mybatis mapper.But why?Should i clear oracle cache everytime?This doesn't feel right.Is there a better solution?
Any answer would be helpful.
thx

application.properties

```
# Spring
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/

# MyBatis
mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true
mybatis.configuration.local-cache-scope=statement
# DataSource 1
spring.datasource.db1.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@*******
spring.datasource.db1.username=***
spring.datasource.db1.password=***
spring.datasource.db1.driver-class-bookName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

mapper

```
@Mapper
@Qualifier("bookMapper")
public interface BookMapper {
    @Select({"select * from book"})
    @Options(useCache = false)
    @Results({
            @Result(property = "bookId",column = "book_id"),
            @Result(property = "bookName",column = "book_name"),
            @Result(property = "bookNumber",column = "book_number")
    })
    List<BookEntity>  getALL();
//    insertBook();
}
```

entity

```
public class BookEntity {
    long bookId;
    String bookName;
    int bookNumber;

    //getters and setters


}
```

Comment: Please add your code. Its very difficult to understand by just looking at text. show your mapper and config class

Comment: Also I would suggest to debug in the Dao layer whether you are getting all records after adding it in the db/

Comment: Added my code now.Can you help me pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to cache clearing.

I think there's no problem except issuing a `commit` after your `insert( a DML )` statement.

If you didn't issue a `commit` you could get only 3 records from another session.

But after you issue,

> alter table book nocache `( a DDL )`

, an *implicit commit* occur, and you could see all 5 records.

Comment: Yes it's the commit that caused this problem!Thx a lot